# WCF Host as windows service faults

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

I have this WCF service running as a window service.

I have in my code that everytime it faults it will restart the service.

Now I'm having the issue where the host faults, it tries to restarts, then faults again, but at some point it just stop the service.

Wondering why it stop the service? Is this something handled by the OS that it detects the service has faulted a number of time within a certain time it will just stop the service because it faulted too many time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe by default a service will only restart so many times.

- Run `service.msc`
- Find your service
- View the Recover tab in its properties dialog

Comment: The subsequent failure If i set it restart service, will it always try to restart the service even if it will always fail?

Comment: @pdiddy There is a "Help me set up recovery actions" help link on that tab.  Other than that I'm not sure where to find more info.  My answer was from memory with a quick of the UI to get the tab names correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to view Event Log, There must be some information in case windiws itself is doing something.